# CSS Multi line rounded Header

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I am trying to create a rounded header that could possible be multiple lines.  My problem is that the left and right images start to repeat themselves if the text needs to go on another line.

*Edit*  If you need the images:  http://www.filedropper.com/corners

CSS

```
.Label
{
    color:White;
}

.Left
{
    background:url('images/tab_left.png') repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    width:12px;
}

.Middle
{
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    background:url('images/tab_mid.png');
    font-weight:lighter;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    color:White;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-top:1px;
    text-align:center;
}

.Right
{
    background:url('images/tab_right.png') repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    width:12px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table style="height:auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="Left"></td>
        <td class="Middle"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Label1" CssClass="Label" /></td>
        <td class="Right"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thsi sort of question may be better answered on doctype.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images that you provided are for one-line only. If you want it to go multiple lines, you will have to do some extra work. Also the images have a gradient, so it will not be possible to use them for multiple lines.

On the other hand, [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) offers a much simpler solution for rounded corners. A lot less pain and flexible.

[Tutorials:Rounded Corners](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Rounded_Corners)

Comment: exactly what i needed to know